# Remove index from jsonify result python

Tags: python, json, flask

So I'm trying to do some deployment with Flask. This is my code:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask import request, jsonify

from kompasscrap import kompas_fun
from detikscrap import detik_fun

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import os.path
import re
from datetime import datetime
import json

scrapdate = str(datetime.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
    def index():
        news_site = request.get_json()
        kompas = bool(news_site.get("kompas"))
        detik = bool(news_site.get("detik"))
        scrapdata = []
        if kompas:
            scrapdata.append(kompas_fun())
        if detik:
            scrapdata.append(detik_fun())

        df = pd.DataFrame(scrapdata)
        list_dct = df.to_dict(orient='records')
        dct = {"date":scrapdate, "data": list_dct}
        return jsonify(dct or {'value': 'error'})

    return app
```

I'm using Postman to do json request. But the output like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "0": {
                "category": "Global",
                "content": "Kemampuan Bersembunyi Pasukan Khusus Inggris, Bisakah Kamu Temukan?, , LONDON, KOMPAS.com - Pasukan Khusus  Inggris dikenal unggul di sejumlah bidang, tetapi  pasukan penembak jitunya mengambil posisi teratas sebagai  ahli penyamaran.",
                "date": "29/11/2020",
                "editor": "Editor Shintaloka Pradita Sicca",
                "headline": "Kemampuan Bersembunyi Pasukan Khusus Inggris, Bisakah Kamu Temukan?",
                "link": "https://www.kompas.com/global/read/2020/11/29/231741970/kemampuan-bersembunyi-pasukan-khusus-inggris-bisakah-kamu-temukan",
                "read count": "325203",
                "tag": "militer",
                "time": "23:17 WIB",
                "total comment": "32",
                "writer": "Penulis Shintaloka Pradita Sicca"
            },
            "1": {
                "category": "Nasional",
                "content": "Gonjang-ganjing Jelang Ganti Kapolri, Geng Solo, Makassar, Pejaten, dan Independen, Host & Produser Eksekutif Program AIMAN | AIMAN setiap senin, Pukul 20.00 WIB di KompasTV, KAPOLRI Jenderal Idham Aziz, akan segera memasuki masa pensiun pada Januari 2021 nanti. Meski bisa diperpanjang, tapi peluang untuk pergantian terbuka lebar.",
                "date": "30/11/2020",
                "editor": "Editor Heru Margianto",
                "headline": "Gonjang-ganjing Jelang Ganti Kapolri, Geng Solo, Makassar, Pejaten, dan Independen",
                "link": "https://nasional.kompas.com/read/2020/11/30/08444511/gonjang-ganjing-jelang-ganti-kapolri-geng-solo-makassar-pejaten-dan",
                "read count": "89950",
                "tag": "kapolri jenderal idham azis",
                "time": "08:44 WIB",
                "total comment": "17",
                "writer": "None"
            }
        }
    ],
    "date": "30-11-2020"
}
```

I already use `orient='records'` when converting to dictionary but index is still there, even become the dictionary itself. And the main date is at the bottom of output instead at the top. Output I desire are like this:

```
{
    "date": "30-11-2020",
    "data": [
        {
            "category": "Global",
            "content": "Kemampuan Bersembunyi Pasukan Khusus Inggris, Bisakah Kamu Temukan?, , LONDON, KOMPAS.com - Pasukan Khusus  Inggris dikenal unggul di sejumlah bidang, tetapi  pasukan penembak jitunya mengambil posisi teratas sebagai  ahli penyamaran.",
            "date": "29/11/2020",
            "editor": "Editor Shintaloka Pradita Sicca",
            "headline": "Kemampuan Bersembunyi Pasukan Khusus Inggris, Bisakah Kamu Temukan?",
            "link": "https://www.kompas.com/global/read/2020/11/29/231741970/kemampuan-bersembunyi-pasukan-khusus-inggris-bisakah-kamu-temukan",
            "read count": "325203",
            "tag": "militer",
            "time": "23:17 WIB",
            "total comment": "32",
            "writer": "Penulis Shintaloka Pradita Sicca"
        },
        {
            "category": "Nasional",
            "content": "Gonjang-ganjing Jelang Ganti Kapolri, Geng Solo, Makassar, Pejaten, dan Independen, Host & Produser Eksekutif Program AIMAN | AIMAN setiap senin, Pukul 20.00 WIB di KompasTV, KAPOLRI Jenderal Idham Aziz, akan segera memasuki masa pensiun pada Januari 2021 nanti. Meski bisa diperpanjang, tapi peluang untuk pergantian terbuka lebar.",
            "date": "30/11/2020",
            "editor": "Editor Heru Margianto",
            "headline": "Gonjang-ganjing Jelang Ganti Kapolri, Geng Solo, Makassar, Pejaten, dan Independen",
            "link": "https://nasional.kompas.com/read/2020/11/30/08444511/gonjang-ganjing-jelang-ganti-kapolri-geng-solo-makassar-pejaten-dan",
            "read count": "89950",
            "tag": "kapolri jenderal idham azis",
            "time": "08:44 WIB",
            "total comment": "17",
            "writer": "None"

        }
    ]
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: The output above is not just 2 dictionary/data. So it can't just remove the "0" or "1".

Answer (score 0):

Well you may try:

```
for i, subdict in enumerate(app['data']):
    for key in subdict.keys():
        for subkey in subdict[key].keys():
            app['data'][i][subkey] = subdict[key][subkey]
        del app['data'][i][key]
```

This will convert the unwanted output you have to your wanted output.

It will iterate through your list of data dictionaries and will remove one level of descending tree by copying the content under the unwanted key to the same level of that unwanted key. Then it will delete the unwanted key and associated content.

Comment: The data it's not just 2.

Comment: what is it? is is a continuous list of integer between 0 and n? In my edit it will make it for all key contained in 'data'

Comment: It's web scraping program. More data scraped, more data got `append` to the list. I just post 2 data as a result because it will be too long.

Comment: as I said: in my edit all keys in 'data' will be deleted and their content copied one level up (so where the deleted key was)

Comment: Is that suited for your needs?

Comment: It keeps throwing `TypeError: 'Flask' object is not subscriptable` error

Comment: well try to list(your_flask) to convert from one object type to the other. Not sure that will work though.